# Pretty-printing with a comment string prefixing a box

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to generate a text file for use in another program. This program only has line-style comments. I want to pretty-print a comment that, whenever the line is broken,  it is prefixed by `//`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
type elaborate_type = A | B

let elaborate_to_string = function
  | A -> "OK, this is type A, but long"
  | B -> "B"

let pp_elaborate chan v = Format.pp_print_string chan (elaborate_to_string v)

Format.printf "@[<hv2>{@,@[<hov>// Here is a long comment I want to break@ // \
               here, but also indent. It should also be the case that anything@ // \
               I put here (such as some complex printable term \"%a\") should@ // \
               only break if it has //, too).@]@,\
               @[...@]\
               @]@,}@."
              pp_elaborate A
```

which gives the output

```
{
  // Here is a long comment I want to break
  // here, but also indent. It should also be the case that anything
  // I put here (such as some complex printable term "OK, this is type A, but long") should
  // only break if it has //, too).
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this without adding the `//@`  to the end of each line I want to break?

Comment: A follow-up question: Suppose I don't have any control over `pp_elaborate`, and somewhere along the line it contains a `\n`. Is that just going to mes up my pretty-printer? Which is to say, I would need to replace the line breaks in the string with spaces?

Comment: Do you want to add a break hint when a `//` is present or do you want to add a `//` at the start of the printed line whenever a line is broken?

Comment: The latter. I was wondering if there was a way to hint to the pretty-printer that, beyond just indenting the line when it is broken, that it should be prefixed by `// `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A option to solving this issue is to update the newline function of the formatter to make it prints `//` right after the newline:

```ml
let add_double_slash_after_linebreak_and_before_indents fmt =
  let fns = Format.pp_get_formatter_out_functions fmt () in
  let out_newline () =
    fns.out_newline ();
    fns.out_string "//" 0 2
  in
  Format.pp_set_formatter_out_functions fmt { fns with out_newline}

let () =
  let () =
    add_double_slash_after_linebreak_and_before_indents Format.std_formatter
  in
  Format.printf "@[<v 2>This tests the formatting@,One line@,two line @]"
```

```
 This tests the formatting
//  One line
//  two line val add_double_slash_after_linebreak_and_before_indents :
```

However, the double slashes `//` will appear at the start of the line independently of the indentation, if you prefer them to appear after the indentation, you can update the indentation function of the formatter instead:

```ml
let add_double_slash_after_linebreak_and_indents fmt =
  let fns = Format.pp_get_formatter_out_functions fmt () in
  let out_indent n =
    fns.out_indent n;
    fns.out_string "//" 0 2
  in
  Format.pp_set_formatter_out_functions fmt { fns with out_indent}



let () =
  let () =
    add_double_slash_after_linebreak_and_indents Format.std_formatter
  in
  Format.printf "@[<v 2>This tests the formatting@,One line@,two line @]"
```

```
This tests the formatting
  //One line
  //two line
```

Concerning your follow-up question, any `\n` in a string will mess up the formatting if there are printed with `%s`. You can avoid this issue by using `pp_print_text` which replaces   and `\n` in the string by calls to `pp_print_space` and `pp_force_line`.